# NameError: global name 'fd' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to run my code but I always get the error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/WWF - Sustainable Hydropower/FRA/Code/f1_zonal_stats.py", line 180, in <module>
    zonal_statistics(*argv)
  File "D:/WWF - Sustainable Hydropower/FRA/Code/f1_zonal_stats.py", line 49, in zonal_statistics
    set_environment(workspace, fd.mask_layer)
NameError: global name 'fd' is not defined
```

I have tried to define fd as global variable but it is still known as an error.
This is my code

```
import csv
import datetime
import os
import sys
import time
from collections import defaultdict
global fd

import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

def zonal_statistics(*argv):

    start = time.clock()
    __location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

    TIMESTAMP = int(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
    print "Starting at %s" % (str(TIMESTAMP))

    workspaceFolder = os.path.join(r"C:\temp\FFR_Results\1_ZonalResults", 'Temp')
    make_sure_path_exists(workspaceFolder)

    workspace = createWorkspace(workspaceFolder, TIMESTAMP)

    # Set environment
    csv_name = r"E:\Dropbox\Projects\FFR\Code\ZonalGridTransfer\FFR_input.csv"

    set_environment(workspace, fd.mask_layer)
```

Comment: Where have you defined fd? the variable hasn't been initialised or given a value. What value is fd supposed to return?

Comment: *I have tried to define fd as global variable*, Where have you?

Comment: Now that you have declared it, it clearly does not hav any attribute `mask_layer`

Comment: I put "global fd" in the line before import arcpy to define fd as global variable, but it still turns out as an error

Comment: @ardinur Like I said in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

<s>There is no definition of fd in your code snippet</s> (I just saw the false definition of fd). To define it as a global variable you have to define it outside of any function and to put changes to it then call it as 'global fd' wherever you want to put changes. However, reading the variable is possible without calling it as global.

```
fd = something
.
.
.
def print():
    print(fd)

def change():
    global fd
    fd = something_else
```